# How to send a batch of email with an interval of 5 mins every month using cron?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I want to perform a cronjob that has an interval of 5 minutes. So I need to send 10 emails every month until the status of all of the emails is set to `1`
In my process after a successful sending of a process I am updating the `sent` status column in my table to `1` and also the `date sent column`. Here's my table structure:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email     | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sent      | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| sent_date | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here's my code for sending email:

```
public function sentEmailToTest() {

    $this->load->library('email');

    $dummy = $this->Users_model->get_dummy_email();

    if(count($dummy) > 0) {

        $config = array(
            'protocol'  =>  'sendmail',
            'smtp_host' =>  'mail.sample.ph',
            'smtp_port' =>  587,
            'mailtype'  =>  'html', 
            'charset'   =>  'utf-8'
        );

        //what is happening every 5 minutes the loop will send the email (only 1 email per 5 minutes)
        foreach($dummy as $d) {

            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->set_mailtype("html");

            $this->email->from('info@sample.ph', 'Sample Admin');
            $this->email->to($d['email']);
            $this->email->cc('user@sample.ph, helloworld@gmail.com');
            $this->email->subject("TEST MESSAGE ONLY USING CRON");
            $this->email->message("TEST FROM SAMPLE");

            $send_mail = $this->email->send();

            if($send_mail) {
                //make update
                $this->Users_model->updateDummyStatus($d['id']);
                return true;
            } else {
                //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            }

        }

    } else {

        //update all sent to 0 and do some validations here...

        exit;

    }

}
```

Here's my model function to get a batch of email with a limit of 10:

```
public function get_dummy_email() {

    $this->db->select('email');
    $this->db->where('sent', 0);
    $this->db->limit(10);
    $this->db->from('tr_dummy_email');
    $client = $this->db->get();

    return ($client) ? $client->result_array() : '';

}
```

And my cron tab is like this:

```
*/5 * * * *
```

But the problem is after running my cron. The first email did not send and it skips to the second email after 5 minutes.

What I want is send a 10 emails every 5 mins. What is happening now is only 1 email is send after 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $this->db->select('email');
```

to

```
     $this->db->select(array('email','id'));
```

because you are using id field....so maybe it causes error on update query line and stops.

Comment: so are u getting the desired output when the function is run without cron

Comment: Ill try it using setInterval and get the 10 emails. And it works. I dont know why the cron doesn't recoginze my loop. :(

Comment: dnt u want to sent 10 emails every 5 mins

Comment: Yeah that is what I want sent 10 email with an interval of 5 minutes. In my current only 1 email is sending.

Comment: leave the setInterval ...i.m asking can you send 10 emails if you call sentEmailToTest() once

Comment: Im doing the interval process in cron. But as a test I just use ajax process to output 10 email. So you mean I'll try to send without cron?

Comment: can u move discussion to chat??......yes without cron or time interval...

Comment: Without cron only 1 email can send. Dont know why. Maybe it's my loop process.

Comment: yes then it is your loop.....check what you are getting from database...echo var_dump($dummy).